# Прокрутка к верху страницы

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи jQuery можно реализовать прокрутку к верху страницы? Или посоветуйте какой-нибудь плагин для jQuery 1.7+. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот [примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mUQyS/) для наглядности.

Comment: Спасибо!скажите а как сделать что бы эта кнопка появлялась через определенное время справа скажем или где то в углу а не внизу страница ?Именно появление ?

Comment: Можно [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mUQyS/3/) поизвращаться.

Comment: кстати, подобная кнопка должна появляться после достаточно длительного скрола, т.е. не после единичного прокрута колёсиком, т.к. с тем же успехом проще сделать обратный прокрут. это так, моё мнение о юзабилити.

Comment: @Spectre, ну так в примере именно это и реализовано, если что )) Увеличиваете значение в этом кусочке:

   if(150 <= currentScrollTop)

Comment: нет-нет-нет, это не к вашему примеру притензии, а подобному функционалу во всяких контактах, хабрах и кинопоисках

Answer (score 4):

т.е. `shift+space` уже не в моде...

```
$('html').scrollTop(0);
```

- [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 2):

[Анимированная прокрутка страницы на jQuery](http://www.rudebox.org.ua/animated-scrolling-rudebox/)